# Virtual and Physical address space being same

Tags: operating-system

Consider a hypothetical situation in which we come up with an Operating System having the same sized physical and virtual address space.Then what are the advantages or disadvantages of putting such a scheme.For starters special hardware support for MMU(Memory Management Unit) is not required.What shall be other implications.

Comment: I fail to see how it would obsolete the MMU or any other hardware.. or is this question about an OS that *doesn't* use virtual memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need for virtual memory doesn't really lie in sizes, but in the fact that it allows a process to not care about other processes.

Each can use their virtual memory freely and the OS makes sure to store all the data in different parts of the physical memory. There are other advantages too, such as swapping certain pages to external memory without the process knowing it.